# change from DefaultHttpClient to HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

I am new in Android development and till now I am using DefaultHttpClient to make service call now I need to use HttpURlConnection as DefaultHttpClient is depricated. How can I achieve this???

My code for DefaultHttpClient is

```
 public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;


            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Constant.statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
```

I am calling this method in doInBackground of my AsyncTask as

```
 ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
                String jsonResponse = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(url, serviceHandler.POST, pairs);
```

Comment: check this ref: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm

Answer (score 1):

To build your URL use this, this is an example:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme(BUILDER_SCHEME) // http
    .authority(BUILDER_AUTHORITY) //api.themoviedb.org
    .appendPath(BUILDER_PATH_1) // 3
    .appendPath(BUILDER_PATH_2) // movie
    .appendPath(params[0]) // now_playing
    .appendQueryParameter(APIKEY_PARAM, "key"); //my api key 
String builtURL = builder.build().toString();
```

The result then is: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=key

Declare your object:

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
```

Initialize:

```
URL url = new URL(builtURL);
httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Set Request method for connection:

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Connect:

```
httpURLConnection.connect();
```

And if you want a status code & response then:

```
httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

This is a pretty simple example though, if you can though, try Retrofit.

Comment: my major concern to set parameters and in your answer you did not right any thing to  set parameters... and i am sending List<NameValuePairs>pairs to the makeServiceCall method

Comment: @raviprakashdarshan, are you referring to the URL? I'll put that in.

Comment: @raviprakashdarshan, I updated my answer, your builder would look slightly different but it's the same concept.